# Problems with css @import in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, css-import

My css code is in two files. One general and one with fonts to be included in different projects easily.

I have `@import url("fonts.css");` instruction in the first line of my general css file which seems to work fine on Chrome, but for some reason Firefox seems to ignore the instruction and the file with fonts is not imported. (I don't see it on "style editor" tab)

If I import the file via "import existing css stylesheet and add to file" option, it is added correctly, but I want it to be imported from the server.

Changing the instruction to `@import "fonts.css";` also doesn't help.

Could you please point me to the right direction with that problem?

Comment: Open Web Developer Tools in Firefox and go to the Network tab to see whether or not the file is being loaded.

Comment: @TimR There is no GET request on fonts.css in the Firefox network tab. (in Chrome there is with status code 200)

Comment: Without having a complete [mcve] there's not a lot we can say. Make sure you test the URL with [a CSS validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Quentin The code is a valid css code according to that website. I'll edit the initial post to add the code example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experimented a bit with code examples and I suppose that Firefox stores imported by `@import` statement css files somewhere and doesn't load new changes without user action (deleting cookies didn't help but `CTRL+SHIT+R` did the magic)